# what should I do for next step?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry if my question is not really programming problem,but I can't find any answer for it.

I hope so that I don't get - vote for my question:D

I read php and mysql,now I know about session,cookie,Database,GD lib,Curl,FTP and socket programming by php,and I read CodeIgniter framework too.
and for Model I read JavaScript,a little VBScript and also jQuery and Ajax.

now I wanna to know what should I do for next step to be good web programmer?which extension should I read and also what should I do?

Comment: To be a good web programmer you should write code for web applications.

Comment: ...start writing code, instead of just reading about it :)

Comment: you'd better build a real app or website. This will probably lead you to other questions depending on what you want to do. Besides, this will let you **practice**, which is the best way to learn

Comment: I think this belongs to "Programmers" ==> http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ and yes, of course, start programming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've read quite enough. The best thing you can do now is working out some examples for yourself. You will find yourself stumbeling across various problems that way and from that point, you can read some more about certain subjects.

Comment: I develop some project to by these,but I wanna to know which part is more important and more usable,then I start to read and learn it.

Comment: @Moein7tl The most important part is the part which is directly related to your particular problem in your particular programming job.